# How can I make the user input alphabet value only for name and surname?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
properties = [("Name", str),("Surname", str),("Age", int),("Height", float),("Weight", float)]
Person={}
def Calc(key,values):
    try:
        value=input(f'Enter the {key}: ')
        check=values(value)
    except:
        print(f'Invalid value for {key}!')
        Calc(key,values)
    else:
        Person.setdefault(key,value)
    
for k,v in properties:
    Calc(k,v)
print(Person)
```

The problem with the following code is that if a user tries to enter an alphanumeric value for name and surname, it doesn't raise an exception because it comes under string but, I want it to raise an exception when the user enters an alphanumeric value. I know I can do it using isalpha() function but then I guess I will have to use if clause to check the type of the object but I guess that's not pythonic(duck typing). What can be the best solution to where I can implement the functionality where user cannot enter the alphanumeric value.

Comment: If you want to keep that same structure, then just define your own validation function for names, and supply that instead of `str` in your dictionary.

Comment: Names are mostly composed of alphanumeric values (though more alpha than numeric), so I think you mean you want to disallow the user from entering _non-alpha_ values. But names also feature non-alpha characters, for example "'", "-", and " " are all fairly common non-alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a custom validation function.

```
def check_alpha(name):
    if not name.isalpha():
        raise ValueError
...
properties = [("Name", check_alpha),("Surname", check_alpha),("Age",int)...
```